# How can I use none_if_empty with create_deep_key?

Tags: google-app-engine, bulkloader

I was looking at [Where are the reference pages of the Google App Engine bulkloader transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817626/where-are-the-reference-pages-of-the-google-app-engine-bulkloader-transform) and figured out most of my bulkloader.yaml configuration with the exception of one case.

One of my Kinds 'Product' has a property called site. If present this is a deep key for a Customer Kind and a Site kind. Now the problem I am having is with the non_if_empty. In the below case it will not ever create the deep key. It always comes back none. If I remove the transform.none_if_empty it will fail as my input file has empty entires for some of these values.  How can I make this work? How can I use none_if_empty with create_deep_key

```
- property: site
  external_name: site
  export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
  import_transform: transform.none_if_empty(transform.create_deep_key(('Customer', 'siteCustomer', True),
                                                ('Site', 'siteId', True)))

  export: 
   - external_name: siteCustomer
     export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string_n(0)
   - external_name: siteId
     export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string_n(1)

Product Bulkloader File Example
name,siteCustomer,siteId
first,,
second,1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

That should be

```
import_transform: transform.none_if_empty(transform.create_deep_key(
    ('Customer','siteCustomer', True),
    ('Site', transform.CURRENT_PROPERTY, True)))
```

Essentially, refer to the current property's import value as transform.CURRENT_PROPERTY.

Comment: In the case above that's actually not what I want but even still if I use your suggestion I end up with a null key even though the two values are set. The keep key is never created. It's always none. I just can't figure out why.

Comment: It's strange too because if I do import_transform: transform.none_if_empty(transform.create_foreign_key('Customer', key_is_id=True)) everything works fine. But if I do the same thing with the create_deep_key function I always get none.

Answer (score 0):

So I still don't know what I am missing here but my work around is thus:

from google.appengine.ext.bulkload import transform

def create_deep_key(*path_info):
    f = transform.create_deep_key(*path_info)

```
def create_deep_key_lambda(value, bulkload_state):

    try:
        return f(value, bulkload_state)
    except:
        return None

return create_deep_key_lambda
```